# Mongo DB convert string to dates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a string date like this 'Sat Apr 02 2022 16:36:53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' and i want to convert this string to an ISO date. My main goal is to compare this string with an input date string in the Mongo DB database.

Is there any way to do so?

I have tried using the $toDate operator but I always get this error
PlanExecutor

> error during aggregation :: caused by :: Error parsing date string 'Sat Nov 06 2021 19:46:08 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'; 41: Double timezone specification 'n'; 47: Double timezone specification 'U'; 53: Double timezone specification 's'; 57: Double timezone specification 'T'; 34: Double timezone specification '('

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: did you try javascript's toISOString() method?

Comment: You should **never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects. You cannot convert it easily directly in Mongo (e.g. in an aggregation pipeline). Go through each document with a loop and correct the data one-by-one. For conversion you may use an external library, e.g. [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) or [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) or [day.js](https://day.js.org/en/)

Answer (score -1):

```
(new Date()).toISOString()
```

Converts your date object to ISO String. You can pass a `dateString` to it, achieving something of the like of

```
(new Date(dateString)).toISOString()
```

Comment: How to access the dateString in an aggregate function?

Comment: @AbhishekSolanki how is your aggregate look-alike?

Comment: {
      $addFields: {
        newTimeStamp: {
          $toDate: "$userActivities.timeStamp"
        }
      }
    } this is my first stage and after then I have a match stage where I match it with a lt operator

Comment: @AbhishekSolanki I'm not very familiar with Mongo, so I can only guess. What is the value of "$userActivities.timeStamp" ?

Comment: It is the date string. Its value is something like this 'Sat Apr 02 2022 16:36:53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'

Comment: @AbhishekSolanki I might be wrong here, but my first guess would be `{ $addFields: { newTimeStamp: { $toDate: "new Date($userActivities.timeStamp).toISOString()" } } }`.

Comment: It is not working. Giving following error. =>


Failed to optimize pipeline :: caused by :: Error parsing date string 'new Date($userActivities.timeStamp)'; 0: passing a time zone identifier as part of the string is not allowed 'n'; 8: Unexpected character '('; 9: Unexpected character '$'; 10: Double timezone specification 'u'; 16: Double timezone specification 't'; 22: Double timezone specification 'e'; 25: Double timezone specification 't'; 31: Double timezone specification 'a'; 4: Double timezone specification 'D'

Comment: @AnonymousCreator now we have a Mongo-specific problem. Since I'm not very experienced with Mongo, I cannot help you unless we have some way to play around with this. I do not have a Mongo-based dev env.

Comment: Hmm. Question was mongo specific only from very beginning.

Comment: @AnonymousCreator that's true. But in many cases the question tags technology1 and technology2 and the solution can be provided knowing only technology1. The question is about string-date comparison, which is supported by Javascript. If my answer can be applied to Mongo, then it's correct. If it cannot be applied, then we will need to find that out, so I will either edit or delete the answer.